# Windows environment variable vs Config file

Tags: php, windows, apache

There is a web app I'm working on. It's PHP based with an Apache web server.

In production servers the application pulls some 'sensitive' information such as the password for the database and the database user name from the Windows environment variables. This is done instead of putting the information into a config file within the application.

I've been using config files myself so I thought about advantages/disadvantages. I don't see much gain from doing it the way they're doing it but I'm sure I'm not thinking about it correctly.

Here is my take :

Disadvantages

1. Anyone that gains access to the windows machine can just go into the windows environment variables and see them anyway.
2. Changing the information cannot be done without shutting down the server. There have been instances where we've changed the environment variables and had to fully shut down apache in order for it to fully reload the new values.

Advantages

1. When moving from dev, to qa, to prod machines the app config files don't have to be changed because each server will have the necessary data already set in the environment variables. ( I don't have to 'remember' to use the correct config file because the environment variables are already set for each server ).
2. Security can be tightened so only admins can actually see the environment variables. Not sure if windows can do this but I'm certain there's some registry editing that can allow this.

What is your point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really talking about is the control of access to sensitive information, and the best way to do this is to use the _access_control_ mechanisms built into the underlying OS.  In my opinion, you can't do this effectively with environment variables at the Apache level, so I find it difficult to think of *any* compelling advantages which would make me support this option.

You can do this using a file to store the content, e.g. a `config.php` file which has the appropriate access control.  Limit the scope of this file to setting only this limited number of parameters to be protected., e.g.

```
<?php
$DBuser   = "abd";
$DBpasswd = 'fred:ere12#';
```

This can only be compromised by someone on the server having read access to the file.  (Even if this is in a web-accessible directory, accessing this by URI would not reveal this info.  Do you see why?)

As paulsm4 suggests obfuscating this by encryption will prevent anyone with casual read access from seeing these data.  *However*, this is not a security mechanism, since we should assume that anyone who has access to the config.php file also has access to the script which reads and decodes these parameters and can simply re-engineer this procedure.

In fact in my applications, I use a slightly different approach, which I give as an example.  I use defines (the apps are OO OO and don't use globals) in a small index.php bootstrap and keep all other configuration data in my D/B

```
<?php
define( 'SQL_CONTEXT', 'DB:user:pwd:tableprefix' );
define( 'ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'START_TIME', microtime() );
// a couple of other app-specific defines go here

if( ( @include( "./_cache/dispatcher.class.php" ) ) != 1 ) {
    require("./_include/functions.php");
}

Dispatcher::dispatch();
```

This is build for dev, my test VM, and prod by an install script which has some edits to insert this sensitive info into the APPROOT/index.php, so that I don't need to keep this sensitive info in my **git** repository.

Comment: Do you see why? Well, apache would still 'serve' it right? but since the script sets php variables and doesn't print anything they woudn't see anything right?
If it were a text config file then it WOULD be seen in a public directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose whichever is more *operationally* convenient for you (it sounds like environment variables make your life easier - then go for it)...

... and then *encrypt* the text string.

Comment: Well, right, both can be convenient. But I was looking for some more pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows NT architecture (8, 7, Vista, XP...)

If User A has a USER environment variable "PASSWORD", then User B (who is not Admin) cannot read User A's USER environment variable "PASSWORD", so it's secure as long as User B is not Admin.

You should be running your different programs as different users.

You should also protect physical access to your computers.